# programmatically add linear layout items to grid layout

Tags: android

I want to programmatically add Linear layouts items to a parent grid layout on a button click.

So first time i click, the grid layout should look like :

```
TextView Button
```

Second time :

```
TextView Button TextView Button
```

Third time :

```
TextView Button TextView Button TextView Button
```

But what is actually happening is :

first time :

```
TextView Button
```

Second time :

```
TextView Button Button
```

Third time :

```
TextView Button Button Button
```

i.e. The existing text view value is updated and a new button is added every time. What am i doing wrong?

this is the parent layout - fragment_add.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/grdl_reminders"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        grid:columnCount="5" />
</ScrollView>
```

this is the item layout - item_reminder.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_reminder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancelreminder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="X"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my fragment, i inflate the item layout into the grid layout on a button click. this is in the onCLickListener :

```
GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grdl_reminders);
//create new item layout
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_reminder, gridLayout, true);
TextView tv_reminder = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_reminder);
Button btn_cancelReminder = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancelreminder);
String selectedTime = "some new value";
tv_reminder.setText(selectedTime);
```

Comment: post your on click listener

Comment: the last section of code is the onclickListener

Comment: check what is returned by inflater.inflate when last param is true

Comment: @pskink thanks! i set it to false and manually added the item to it's parent. worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of attaching the item to it's root in the inflate method, i manually add it the parent.
i.e.

Use `false` as the third parameter to `inflate()` :

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_reminder, gridLayout, false);
```

and use `addView()` in the end :

```
gridLayout.addView(v);
```